Flutter background_location crashes on initialisation
On an iOS device, I am successfully requesting permission, but when calling the startLocation Service the app just exits
BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();

Running in debug mode, I can see this error

*** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:], CLLocationManager.m:972
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
satisfying: !stayUp || CLClientIsBackgroundable(internal->fClient) || _CFMZEnabled()'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1808ffc60 0x19812fee4 0x1820a4c80 0x1878541b0 0x102190f54 0x1021912c0 0x102190a98 0x102190b30
0x1056ba8b8 0x10513c58c 0x1805bf094 0x1805c0094 0x18056cd44
0x18056c994 0x1808bb014 0x1808784f8 0x18088b174 0x1a13ca988
0x18308da88 0x182e26f78 0x197217ee4 0x1020485c8 0x102048540
0x102048644 0x10226c4d0) libc++abi: terminating with uncaught
exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x00000001bb1e3bbc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8

I am not sure what this means or how to deal with it.

As the official documentation of apple state:

Important
This key is required if your iOS app uses APIs that access the user’s location information while the app is in use.

And the package documentation:

Make sure to declare all required permissions for both your android and IOS app

if you want to use location service you need to add this into your ios/Runner/info.plist:
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location.</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>

